# is it possible to show an annotation once the map loads in monotouch?

Tags: mapkit, xamarin.ios

I've set up the map to load an `MKAnnotation` when the map loads, but it will only show the pin, and not the text that I've set up inside the annotation. Is there a fake event I can call to make it show at once, or even a property?

Answer (score 2):

The title property on the MKAnnotation is only used for callouts.  You should call SelectAnnotation on the MKMapView object when you want it to be displayed.